# How to configure QoS per IP basis?

Tags: linux, bandwidth, nat, tc, qos

We have say `4` users in a private network connected to the Internet trough a `Linux router` with a `public IP` address that is doing `network address translation` (NAT). I have to configure `QoS` to give access to the users to `Internet` but with throttled bandwidth for `2` users while for others no limitations.

```
eth0:121.51.26.35
eth1:10.239.107.1
```

`eth0` of `Linux Router` is a `10Mbps` link. `eth1` is connected to `switch` and `4` nodes are connected to the `switch`.
I want configure `tc` to throttle bandwidth of `2 nodes` only i.e. a group of users `(XyZ in picture)` to use only `3Mbps` cumulatively. (When 1 user will be downloading/uploading, he/she must get `3Mbps` but when 3 users are downloading/uploading simultaneously they must receive `1MBps` )

**First please let me know is the requirement achievable**,
if yes how shall I proceed?

Below is the topology

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pick a class aware qdisc like HFSC or HTB.

Then you'll have to build a class tree like this:

```
Root Class (10MBit)
|
\--- XyZ Class (rate 3Mbit ceil 3Mbit)
|    |
|    \--- Client 10 (rate 1.5Mbit ceil 3Mbit)
|    \--- Client 11 (rate 1.5Mbit ceil 3Mbit)
|
\--- Client 30 (rate 3.5Mbit ceil 10Mbit)
\--- Client 40 (rate 3.5Mbit ceil 10Mbit)
```

And that on both interfaces (for upload and download shaping).

With HTB to get predictable results you should make sure that the sum of children is always equal to parent. So Root has 10Mbit, and its direct children equal (Xyz 3Mbit + Client30 3.5Mbit + Client40 + 3.5Mbit == 10Mbit). Likewise XyZ has 3Mbit and its children Client10+Client11.

Years and years ago I wrote a script that did something similar:

https://github.com/frostschutz/FairNAT

It's unmaintained today, but maybe it can give you some ideas anyway.

Traffic shaping in Linux was a bit of an neglected/esoteric field, hard to find good documentation too. Not sure if that ever changed...

There is http://lartc.org/  (ignore the wondershaper part)

and the Kernel Packet Traveling Diagram http://www.docum.org/docum.org/kptd/ (also the FAQ)

Or if that's all to complicated, maybe a stateless qdisc like ESFQ will do the trick for you. It tries to achieve some kind of equilibrium between clients without actually applying any hard bandwidth limits.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer, Well, 
Okay I've understood the tree you want me to create on `eth1`, are you suggesting me to create same `class tree ` on `eth0` which is public interface?  
 how will `eth0` know about the client addresses? They would have been NATed when they reach `eth0` , no? 
What I'm missing?

Comment: You're only shaping outgoing traffic, so you (or rather, iptables or nftables I guess) should know which client it belongs to and mark the packets accordingly.

Comment: Okay so I'm doing it on `egress` traffic from `Linux Router` to `Local Network` I should build `class tree` on `eht1` right? 

Then why should I build `class tree` on `eth0`? I mean what I'm understanding wrong?

Comment: eth0: upload, eth1: download. If you want to shape both directions you need qdisc on both interfaces. You can influence downloads only indirectly (delay or drop tcp packets and hope the other side will take the hint).